# Program run on iOS 5.1 device can't find SDK with Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, build, ios6

When i run my project at iOS 5.1 simulator , it shows

```
yld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/3A003E5F-2C66-494F-BCC1-C3EE82F01464/dogTree.app/dogTree
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

And I don't have 5.1 SDK. But why library search path is 5.1 not 6.0?

All my project and be run at iOS 6.0 device, but when I install then at iOS 5.0 or 5.1 device, it crash and show like the following message.

Please give me some help, is it necessary for iOS 5.1 SDK to run iPhone 5.1 simulator?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that I had simply forgotten to change the target platform in an included project. Xcode automatically switches target to the latest iOS when upgrading. Just changing the target for the included project fixed this.

Comment: what target should i change to ?

Answer (score 3):

I have met similar issue, and solved by set the deployment target to 4.3 (the same as my app's minimum version) for each static library depended on. 
I found that the static library depended on was 6.0 as default, and that must cause some library missing when the compatibility was needed for lower version.

Answer (score 2):

For libraries, such as pods, its in  the build settings at iOS Deployment Target.