# Google Drive SDK and iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, google-drive-api

Is the SDK compatible with iOS 5 or only with iOS 6 ?

Everything is fine with the Google exemple and iOS 6 (simulator and devices) but Xcode return a runtime error with iOS 5.1 (simulator and devices).

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2.

**I've already checked the iOS Deployment target. It's set on 5.1.**

Google exemple : https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios

Runtime error returned :

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
 Referenced from: /Users/Borongaj/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/FC5B32F0-C5E6-4054-BE81-4F52054AC911/Tests Google Drive.app/Tests Google Drive
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation


dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
Referenced from: /Users/Borongaj/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/FC5B32F0-C5E6-4054-BE81-4F52054AC911/Tests Google Drive.app/Tests Google Drive
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686009/program-run-at-ios5-1-device-cant-find-sdk-at-xcode-4-5 don't have the time to try it out ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I've just found the solution. It seems that addind this project build setting solved the problem : GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC supported. I hope it can help the world (it's not documented on Google Drive SDK website).

Comment: Oops ! Works on Simulator but not on devices :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The Google documentation omit some important things :

1. watch the Google video **instead** of reading the Google tutorial (text), because some drag/drop can corrupt Xcode buildings preferences
2. **Add GTLDrive_Sources.m inside Project > Build Phases > Compile Sources**
3. switch the GTL project iOS Deployment Target option to 5.1 (or anything else).

With these three steps, you avoid some boring error message.

**Even the Google engineer get same errors during video !** :-)

Comment: @brush51 Right here: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios#optional_view_a_quickstart_video

Comment: hi @Borongaj , after following your suggestion, I still get the same error as you have posted. Any idea how to try resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

I set iOS Development target to **5.1.1** on my Xcode 6.1.1 to solve this issue.