# lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found Error with iOS - GDrive Integration

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, google-drive-api

I saw the video at GDrive Quickstart iOS Page (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios). I followed it step by step, re-tried several times in my iPhone App, & even watched the video. Am trying to integrate GDrive into my existing iphone App.

I imported GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h & GTLDrive.h & added this to my .h file :
@property (nonatomic, strong) GTLServiceDrive *driveService;

In .m :

```
// Helper to check if user is authorized
- (BOOL)isAuthorized
{
    return [((GTMOAuth2Authentication *)self.driveService.authorizer) canAuthorize];
}


// Handle completion of the authorization process, and updates the Drive service
// with the new credentials.
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Authentication Error - %@", error.localizedDescription);
        self.driveService.authorizer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.driveService.authorizer = authResult;
    }
}


-(void) uploadFile : (NSString *) appFile {

    NSLog(@"uploadFile %@", appFile);

    // Initialize the drive service & load existing credentials from the keychain if available
    self.driveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
    self.driveService.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
                                    authForGoogleFromKeychainForName : kGDriveKeychainItem
                                    clientID : kGDriveClientID
                                    clientSecret : kGDriveClientSecret];
    NSLog(@"auth done");

    GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
    file.title = fileStat;
    file.descriptionProperty = @"App Info";
    file.mimeType = @"text/plain";

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile : appFile];
    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                       uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    NSLog(@"Uploading to GDrive");
    [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                      GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) {
                      if (error == nil)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"File ID: %@ ; GDrive file saved!", insertedFile.identifier);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"GDrive - An error occurred: %@", error);
                      }
                  }];
}
```

Am getting the error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

after the line "upload file" (it prints this line & then crashes).

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does your copy of GData weak link either libSystem or libObjC?

Comment: @CodaFi I gave 'copy files if needed' whenever I dragged & dropped GDrive files. Should be ok right? Or should I place that (copy-paste in folder) in the App?

Comment: Any change this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474753/google-drive-sdk-and-ios-5-1?