# Xcode 5 : _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy crash on iOS 5.x devices/simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode5

When I run my app either on a **iOS 5.0 Simulator** or on a **iPad running iOS 5.1.1**, both crash at opening with this message:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy   Referenced from: /Users/antony/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/3ED8B785-0D57-4878-9486-194BABE1C802/Les
>   Orres.app/Les Orres   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

After hours of googling, I've found a lot of people advising to check iOS Deployment Target. So I did it: both in my '**Project**' and '**Target**' tabs, the '**Deployment Target**' value is set to "**5.0**"

Like this post did:
[Program run on iOS 5.1 device can't find SDK with Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686009/program-run-at-ios5-1-device-cant-find-sdk-at-xcode-4-5)

And it still crashes... I have no static library in my project and I'm using Xcode 5 (and started to code it with Xcode 4.5). Anyone else got that issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure what was wrong?